# Flash flash message appended to text area

Tags: javascript, flask, flash-message

I am trying to retrieve flash messages and append them in a text area on a webpage. The function works without the flask/flash provided code but trying to mix flash code with javascript is not working. I am calling this function with a onclick="get_flash();"  The onclick does work without the flash code embedded.

```
head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function get_flash(){
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
    {{% if messages %}
         {% for message in messages() %}
             document.getElementById('msg_box').innerHTML+={{message}};
         {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `messages` without the parentheses?

Comment: I did. No change. I cut out one line at a time from the function to see which line is problematic.  The function becomes undefined  even with the first line as the only line. The function works if I only leave in only the one  document.getElement line.

Answer (score 1):

Your code leads to an Unexpected identifier error. Put quotations around your `{{message}}` variable.

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
          document.getElementById('msg_box').innerHTML += "{{message}}";
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: I thought that when you get_flashed_messages  the que at the server was emptied and that subsequent calls would return empty. Is there something wrong with this code that continues to append the last message. I have a setInterval calling get_flashed_message every second.

  {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
   {% if messages %}
    var strng = "";
    const div = document.getElementById('msg_box');
    {% for message in messages %}
     strng = "{{message}}" + "\r";
     div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', strng);
    {% endfor %}
   {% endif %}
  {% endwith %}
 }